# Can a tournament be FIDE rated if it has multiple time controls based on player ratings

Tags: rules, fide, time-control

If we ran a weekly club tournament that has different time controls for different games based on both players' ratings as set forth in [the FIDE regulations](https://new.uschess.org/tournament-directors/fide-rated-events#rating-regulations), would the tournament qualify as a  Standard rated non-norm event? Or do all games played in the tournament need to follow the same time control?

Comment: Would also be interesting for a weekend tournament as it would let lower rated players have more games.

Answer (score 3):

According to [FIDE Rating Regulations effective from 1 January 2022](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/B022022) you can submit games from different players for rating where different time controls are used to accommodate different player ratings. FIDE rates games rather than tournaments, however the way it receives those results for rating is via tournament report forms (TRF). The tournaments those TRFs come from have to be registered with FIDE and part of the registration process requires one time control to be specified for the entire tournament. That registration has to be performed by your national federation.

That suggests two possible approaches which you would need to run past your national federation who will be your link with FIDE.

1. Run your one tournament as 3 separate tournaments with time controls of 90+30, 60+30 and 30+30 and allocate the games to the 3 tournaments according to the ratings of the players of the individual games.
2. Have one tournament with one advertised time control of 90+30 but run games with time controls according to the players ratings.

Whichever approach you decide to take you will need to be open about it and get the approval of your national federation who will be submitting games for rating to FIDE and who will be responsible if FIDE are not happy.

Comment: @Scott Last time that I organized a FIDE tournament, many years ago, the national federation was the one that has to submit the results. So, BEFORE you organize a tournament, you NEED to negotiate with your national federation. In general, if your national federation does not approve the organization of a FIDE tournament, you would not be able to do it. For that reason, beside checking the FIDE regulations, you need to check also the regulations of your national federation. I have organized several FIDE tournaments through my life. Congratulations for the idea!!! Best of luck!!!